# Does the Microsoft Beauty of the Web site work with IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I am using Internet Explorer Version 9.0.8112.16421 ( IE9 ) on Windows Server Standard 2008 Service Pack 2 64-bit.

When I navigate to http://www.beautyoftheweb.com I can't view any of the showcase apps.  All I see is a blue bar along the top, the IE9 logo, and a footer along the bottom.  Do I need the IE10 beta?  What am I missing?

I notice that there are some script errors with Modernizer on the page.  Is it possible the site is just broken at the moment?

Comment: This page is supposed to work with IE9 - originally the whole point of it was to advertise feature compliance in IE9!  I know we did some DWM stress level testing using it as an easy hardware-accelerated webpage under IE9.  Maybe it's just broken.

Comment: It works for me in IE9. Are you sure you don't have a ad-block extension or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Does the Microsoft Beauty of the Web site work with IE9**

No†, it works with Chrome‡.

The site has IE9 ads (which might suggest it is expected to work with IE9) but it told me Chrome was an outdated version of IE and invited me to "upgrade" to IE8!

> **Is it possible the site is just broken at the moment?**

The site wasn't broken in any obvious way at the time I looked at it with Chrome and wrote this answer. However I only looked at the entry page and "amazing sites" and picked the first "amazing site"

† <sub>based on your report.</sub>
‡ <sub>based on my experience just now</sub>

Comment: I guess you are correct; I can't deny my own experience with the site. For what it's worth, setting Browser Mode to "IE9" and Document Mode to "IE8 standards view" seems to make the site work in IE9.